# How to allow file types for upload in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, bluespice

I'm using MediaWiki 1.23.10 with a BlueSpice extension and tried to add a file extension which would be allowed for a file upload (namely a .dwg file). Reading the documentation I thought that I find a complete list of allowed files under $wgFileExtensions in the LocalSettings.php, but no.

Then I thought perhaps this could be done directly on the Special:Upload page but on this page there is no VisualEditor present.

Anybody have any ideas how to accomplish this? Many thanks for your help!

Comment: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgFileExtensions should do fine. How did you update it in *LocalSettings.php* and what happened when you tried to upload?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I just found it: wiki - Special Pages - Blue Spice - BlueSpice administration - Preferences - BlueSpice - Allowed file extensions